# How can you find out the location of the "My DropBox" folder?

Tags: dropbox, delphi-2007

The installation default for the Dropbox sync folder is [My documents]\My Dropbox.  I recall that it is possible to choose other locations however.  How can I find out at run-time from my D2006 app where the user has placed his/her Dropbox folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at this post from the Dropbox forums: http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=9018

Previous poster was close, but it is stored in the host.db file.  Sample path from my Win7 machine:

`C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\host.db`

For testing, you can try out this online tool to see if you can successfully decode the base64 string: http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/

Comment: Well, have a look into the `dropbox.db` file. It will be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is stored base64 encoded in the SQLite database file located at

`%APPDATA%\Dropbox\dropbox.db` (Win7/Vista)

Table `config` column `dropbox_path` data format is `V<dropboxpath>\np1\n.` (where `\n` is newline char).

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.dropbox.com/help/4584, as of DB version 2.8 you can find the info.json file which contains

```
{
    "business": {
        "host": 123456789,
        "path": "/Users/<USERNAME>/Dropbox (<BUSINESS_NAME>)"
    },
    "personal": {
        "host": 123456789,
        "path": "/Users/<USERNAME>/Dropbox (Personal)"
    }
}
```

It will be in ~/.dropbox/info.json on linux/mac systems, or %APPDATA%\Dropbox\info.json or %LOCALAPPDATA%\Dropbox\info.json on Win.  This is the same path where the other user found host.db.